# How to avoid repeated conditions inside case statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I clean up this a bit? I want to get rid of the unnecessary code like all the repeated `a.question == f.question` comparisons I use on each `case` statement:

```
def notifications_lookup(filters, answers)
    filters.flat_map do |f|
      answers.select do |a|
        case a.question.question_type
        when "image"
          a.question == f.question && a.answer_image.image_id == f.answer.to_i
        when "single"
          a.question == f.question && a.choice_answer.choice_id == f.answer.to_i
        when "list"
          a.question == f.question && a.choice_answer.choice_id == f.answer.to_i
        when "multiple"
          a.question == f.question && !(f.answer.split(",").map(&:to_i) & a.answer_multiple.choices.map(&:id)).empty?
        when "rating"
          results = verify_condition(f, a)
          a.question == f.question && results.any?
        else
          a.question == f.question
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def verify_condition(filter, a)
    a.answer_raitings.map do |r|
      r.raiting == filter.raiting && filter.answer.split(",").map(&:to_i).include?(r.response)
    end
  end
```

Comment: This situation usually happens when you haven't thought out the logic well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember Ruby lets you do these things in several simple passes. There's no need to do it all in one go:

```
def notifications_lookup(filters, answers)
  filters.flat_map do |f|
    answers.select do |a|
      a.question == f.question
    end.select do |a|
      case a.question.question_type
      when "image"
        a.answer_image.image_id == f.answer.to_i
      when "single", "list"
        a.choice_answer.choice_id == f.answer.to_i
      when "multiple"
        !(f.answer.split(",").map(&:to_i) & a.answer_multiple.choices.map(&:id)).empty?
      when "rating"
        verify_condition(f, a).any?
      else
        true
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Another quick fix was to combine two clauses that had the same code.

You might make this even easier by writing a `==` method on your Answer model that can do the comparison for you.

Comment: "...writing a `==` method on your Answer model that can do the comparison for you". Yes. This can make a big difference in the readability of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can select on just `a.question == f.question` and then the results of that select can be used in a further select.

```
def notifications_lookup(filters, answers)
    filters.flat_map do |f|
      selected_answers = answers.select {|a| a.question == f.question}
      selected_answers = selected_answers.select do |a|
        case a.question.question_type
        when "image"
          a.answer_image.image_id == f.answer.to_i
        when "single"
          a.choice_answer.choice_id == f.answer.to_i
        when "list"
          a.choice_answer.choice_id == f.answer.to_i
        when "multiple"
          !(f.answer.split(",").map(&:to_i) & a.answer_multiple.choices.map(&:id)).empty?
        when "rating"
          results = verify_condition(f, a)
          results.any?
        else
          true
        end
      end
    end
  end
```